# Can the cosmological constant be coupled to redshift of radiation

Tags: cosmology, general-relativity, redshift, space-time, dark-energy

Can space-time be more embedded with the things inside it than we actually think?Can the redshift of radiation be a property of spacetime and that dark energy exists only to conserve the overall energy of the universe?

Comment: The energy density of the radiation goes as $a^{-4}$, but the energy density of the dark energy is constant.  So, they do not track each other.  However, there seems to be a conspiracy that made the universe flat, ie $\Omega = \Omega_m +  \Omega_{rel} + \Omega_{\Lambda} = 1$